# turtle.shapesize not working if I use a .gif shape

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make an animation in turtle and I am using sprites from the internet. I wanted to shrink the size of my sprites but the `turtle.shapesize()` is not changing the size of the turtle

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0)
screen.addshape("mario.gif")
sprite = turtle.Turtle()
sprite.speed(0)
sprite.shape("mario.gif")
sprite.penup()
sprite.shapesize(5, 5, 1)

while True:
    screen.update()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `.shapesize()` and most other turtle shape tweaking only applies to polygonal shapes.  (The Tkinter Canvas that the `turtle` module uses doesn't support those kinds of transformations on images.)

Comment: any suggestions about how can I make animations in turtle. I know pygame is the way to go but I could not find a suitable way to integrate it with tkinter.

Comment: Testing confirms @jasonharper's comment but the turtle documentation only says that image turtle shapes do not *rotate*, it says nothing about *scale*.  So what you tried to do is reasonable -- unfortunately, just not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Shapesize does change the size of the turtle but not of the gif image itself.

You can resize the shape at ezgif.com and swap gifs during the game 
eg

```
sprite.shape('mario1.gif')

if sprite.distance(sprite2) <= 20:

    sprite.shape('mario2.gif')
```